# Error with wxWidgets minimal app

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I recently began learning wxWidgets. As all learners do, I first wrote and tested the Minimal App (on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). It worked like a charm.

I then decided to test the application on my Windows 7 PC. I built wxWidgets (Debug and Release builds) using Visual C++ 2008 Express following instructions from [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2009/12/16/how-to-compile-a-wxwidgets-application-in-visual-studio-2008/). I also built the Minimal App (Build and Release configurations) following the same instructions. The application worked perfectly on my computer. To check whether there were any problems, I sent the executable to a friend of mine. He tested it on his XP PC and it gave him the following error:

*The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more details.*

I have checked that I am using the Multithreaded setting in the build options for both the Debug and Release versions of my application. However, neither of the generated executables works on my friend's machine.

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the C/C++ runtime libraries.

The simplest solution is to build both the wxwidgets libraries and the application with the /MT switch rather than the /MD switch in Project | Properties | C++ | Code generation | runtime libraries